# Has Brandon Sanderson ever alluded to a novel/series where we get cross-Cosmere fights?

Tags: cosmere

Has Brandon Sanderson ever alluded to, or outright said "Yeah, I will do this!" to a novel or series that involves cross-Cosmere fighting?

By this, I mean Allomancers vs Radiants. Radiants vs AonDor users etc.

I think it's just such a great idea.. And Brandon's level of parallel thinking is unparalleled, it wouldn't surprise me if (and I'm kind of expecting that he has!) he has said that he's planned this style of story for the future!

P.S - I'm expecting this information to come mainly from Q&As, I've looked myself but haven't found anything so far.

Comment: Well we know/suspect the kings wit. Is a full mistborn as well as a user of the other forms of "magic" in the different worlds. And i believe we will have a book from his POV so if he ever fights we may have cross pollenization ( words?)

Comment: Yes, I believe the name he goes by in the majority of the series is _Hoid_, I was hoping for more of a gladiatoral setting or something like that. From what I've been able to glean so far is that the different magic systems (unique to each shard/world) don't interact well with each other. For instance Allomancy and Feruchemy are of the same world, and interact with each other positively. However Surgebinding against even Shardplate armour we know does not work, which hints at Shard weapons & armour being of a different world to Roshar! Hmmmmmmm!

Comment: @Stormie i think its way to early to jump to conclusions like that about plate, and blades, since we know the radiants were able to fly in there plate while the "dead" plate we have now cannot, plate imo is just going to be specific to a certain type of spren we just havent seen yet, since we know spren cause surgebinding AND blades.

Comment: I don't think it's too large a jump in logic though, especially as we know that Spren are slivers, we know that the Knights Radiant were founded before Odium killed Honour and we also know that Spren were around before Honour was killed. The Spren still work, shardplate doesn't work quite the same as it used to.. Coincidence? ;)

Comment: Additionally, the original ten honor blades were copied by the honor spren, attempting to replicate what was gifted to man. (Blades are of this world, I'm afraid, just made by the local shard)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As far as I know (having just quickly scanned through the compiled Words of Brandon), Brandon has been extremely vague on this topic, but yes, the idea of cross-Cosmere fighting has come up at least twice.

First, someone asked him almost the exact question you did, and he deftly avoiding giving a real answer. Instead, we got a teaser:

> Q:  Will you ever have characters use the different systems of magic openly in front of each other?
>
> A:  I'll warn you this, the third Mistborn trilogy is a space opera, which will involve travel between planets.

He has already said more than once that the third Mistborn trilogy will be the place where the Cosmere as an entity takes the forefront, much more significantly that what we've seen even in *The Stormlight Archives*. So, it seems likely that the various world hoppers we've seen will come into conflict at some point during that series. (On a probably related note, he's made comments that imply that Sazed is going to be *very* important in the Cosmere end-game, because he's the only know dual Shardholder.)

However, he has also briefly talked about what would happen in someone with one kind of magic left their home world, and it's not as obvious as you'd thing:

> Q:  If an Elantrian bonded to a Seon and traveled to Roshar, would that act as a Nahel bond?
>
> A:  It would act very very similarly, yes. But it would be like… it wouldn't necesarily do the exact same things.  It would be treated the exact same way, but wouldn't grant the same powers.

The thing to note here is that, once the person left Sel for Roshar, the bond they had with their Seon would "work similarly" and "be treated the exact same way" as the bond a Roshar native would have with a spren. In order words, the person would still have some kind of investiture, but it won't be *the same* as what they are used to back home. This lines up pretty well with what we know about magic in the Cosmere: magic on the Shard worlds is caused by the interaction of the Shards with each other and their environment. Remove any aspect of that setup (say, leave the vicinity of the Shard) and the magic changes.

Based on these answers, it seems highly likely that we're going to see two magic users from two different worlds duke it out eventually, though probably not for a few more novels. But it's also likely that such a fight isn't going to be a straight up Allomancy vs. AonDor fight that you're imagining -- it will be much weirder.

Comment: Fantastic answer bro, I'm gonna have to hop on chat sometime to have-at some Cosmere theories! :D

Comment: "it will be much weirder." knowing Sanderson, I can't wait to see how *weird* this ends up being.